# jQuery UI plugin is missing?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have download the `CCK`, `Views` and `Panel` modules of Drupal 6 and I also downloaded their dependencies. But every time I save the configuration an error message always comes out. This message,

```
The jQuery UI plugin is missing. Download and extract it into the sites/all/libraries directory. Rename the extracted folder to jquery.ui. (Currently using jQuery UI Not found)
```

I'm pretty sure I have downloaded the right file and also extracted and put it on the right directory but this keeps coming up. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Copy the jquery_ui module directory to your sites/all/modules directory, so it is located in sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/
- [Download the jQuery UI 1.6 release]: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/downloads/list?q=1.6
- Put the downloaded archive into the directory /sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui-1.6.zip
- Extract the archive (/sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui-1.6/)
- Rename the sub-directory into "jquery.ui" (/sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/)
- so the actual jQuery UI JavaScript files are located in: /sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/*.js

Comment: If you still getting the error, then you should create version.txt file which contains just "1.9.2" in it. jquery.ui/version.txt